# Tree-view in AngularJS with customizable node template

Tags: templates, angularjs, treeview

I want to create a directive that will take tree-like data and feed it to some tree-view script (that uses markup as input), using specific HTML template to render nodes. So, directive takes data + node template as input, inserts DOM subtree, and then calls third-party plugin to make it sortable (http://dbushell.github.com/Nestable/ is on my mind, if this matters).

I have a solution, but it is far from being elegant. Here is HTML code (full sample can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/DQjve/):

```html
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree.html">
        <div>
            <ng-include src="'branch.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="branch.html">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="leaf in leaf.children" ng-include src="'leaf.html'">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="leaf.html">
        <ng-include src="template"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'branch.html'"></ng-include>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="my-leaf.html">
        <span style="display: block; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 4px; background: yellow; margin: 3px 0; padding: 4px;">{{leaf.name}}</span>
    </script>

    <tree root="tree" template="my-leaf.html"></tree>
</div>
```

Desired code would look like this:

```html
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <tree root="tree" template="my-leaf.html">
        <span style="display: block; border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 4px; background: yellow; margin: 3px 0; padding: 4px;">{{leaf.name}}</span>
    </tree>
</div>
```

Goals:

1. (less important) Put all utility templates inside directive JavaScript code.
2. (more important) Use contents of the <tree> tag as node template.

But I cannot find the solution.

For point 1: Probably, I need to use `$templateCache` to pre-cache my templates? With some unique template names? Is there any better solution?

For point 2: Should I use `ngTransclude` for p.2? If yes, how? Is there a way to get contents of initial <tree> tag as a string, before any compilation occurs?

Comment: The following link has the directive hope this might help you, http://logically-thinking.blogspot.com/2013/07/angular-treeview-directive-01v.html.

Comment: If someone looking for answer I think it would be helpful https://github.com/ca77y/angular-ya-treeview